# Is this electricity box near shower dangerous?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, walls

I'm remodeling bathroom, and rewiring, but I don't understand much about electricity in bathroom. In the picture you see a white plate on wall covering some kind of conduit or circuitry that leads wires from outside to lights and plugs inside the bathroom. Looks dangerous to me so asked electricians and they said it's fine to have electricity in bathroom. Is this correct?

I've researched and seems in some countries you can't have electricity or outlets in bathroom, but I plan to add two outlets near sink with power coming from this "junction box" thing or whatever it's called.

[image]

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Also, is the box rated/listed for wet location service?

Comment: I'm in a third world country, so there is no code to follow. But I want a safe bathroom. Usually each room has a "junction box" near the ceiling like in pic, that routes wires into the room from outside living area/hallway. It's usually I'm told useful for inspections if something is wrong. Box probably not rated for anything.

Comment: Thre's ALWAYS a Code.  Because even in lawless areas, there are.always consequences for injuring someone. It will go *way better for you* if you can safely say you wired to code. If your power is 120/240 split phase, your default code is US NEC.  If your power is 220-240 single phase, your default Code is EU code, though, complying with NEC wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: You can't have 'safe' either.  You can make things safER, but there isn't some line you can cross after which you're safe and before which you are not.  In many Central American countries it's common to have a 240v outlet next to the shower head for a water-heating shower-head.  If that cover plate is plastic or metal and properly caulked, I wouldn't worry about its safety.

Comment: Here we closer to EU and use 2 pronged plugs (no ground I guess). The plate in the pic is not an outlet and can't be, it's just bundled wires rerouted to different directions in room. The plate is plastic and not caulked. I'm getting conflicting views, some say no electricity at all in bathroom others not. Which is it? No code for real that any follow

Comment: plastic..... without caulk, does it have an o-ring inside of it?

Comment: No just screwed into wall like in every room unless painted over. It's pretty standard here, but since I read no electricity supposed to be in bathroom thought what if I relocated it outside the bathroom would help?

Comment: If you can get to the back side of the wall you could flip it around or even better, if it's possible, move it to the attic where it isn't in direct contact with the water. As you can see in the other comments no one likes the idea of keeping it there no matter where you are located. Stay safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general this is a bad idea in large part because metal drains cause you to be a conductor to ground and water provides various ways for the exposed wire to make contact with you. However if the junction were grounded AND the ground were protected with GFCI then this would pass as safe. Most code still doesn't allow you to have outputs or junctions near running water that are not GFCI.

If you rewire simply don't expose a junction (that includes any broken wire in the walls) near the shower. You can pass insulated wire within the shower facing walls however.

I'm going to guess this junction was on purpose to provide either power for a shower heater or for outlets but since was covered up.